# UIWebView on scrollView resize the height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

Ihave a `UIWebView` on a scroll view. I want to disable scrolling for my web view. It should scroll when the main scroll view scrolling.But my problem is when the webview content is long I cant see the bottom lines. I am resizing the webview like this.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Script", withExtension: "js")!
    let javascript = try! String(contentsOfURL: url)

    self.webvw.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascript)
    var frame:CGRect=webView.frame
    frame.size.height=1
    let fittingSize:CGSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    frame.size=fittingSize
    self.webvw.frame=frame
    self.mainScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.webvw.frame.origin.y+self.webvw.frame.size.height)

    self.hud.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
}
```

But still same. Didn't help me that. How can I solvethis pronlem.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebViews have built in scrolling. If you want to scroll through WebView's content, you would not need to use `UIScrollView`.

However, if you choose to do so, (I would not recommend), then you must set
you `UIWebView`'s instance's `scrollEnabled` to `false`.

And then you will have to track you UIScrollView's content offset, and match `UIWebView`'s scroll's content offset to that value. Doesn't seem like a good idea though. You can just scroll webview itself (without having to use `UIScrollView`).

And to get UIScrollView's content offset, you must override didScroll method of scrollView delegate.